# RShinyapps Deploy Fails with no error message

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny, aws-step-functions, shinyapps

I'm deploying a shiny app to shinyapps.io using AWS Step Functions.  It deploys successfully when I deploy using an EC2 instance spun up from an AMI, but does not deploy when I use the same AMI in AWS Step Functions.  Even worse, I don't get any error message.  The output of the deployApp function is this:

```
Waiting for task: 1353799412
  building: Building image: 9470788
  building: Installing system dependencies
  building: Fetching packages
  building: Building package: maps
## Begin Task Log ##############################################################
## End Task Log ################################################################
No traceback available
```

From this, it seems like it starts to deploy, but then stops.  Any ideas?  I can post code if it's helpful to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Yes please, share any/all code/commands/output needed to reproduce the issue if possible.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your specifics, but here is advice.  1. The cloud web server probably requires your app on port 80.  This is not the default port for Shiny, so you should change this.  2. It's easier to debug server issues with a minimal Shiny app first. 3. It can be effective to test the app from a terminal that gives you more control and output instead of a web server.  Perhaps a VM, or find a way to exec into the container.  4. Be careful of global variables in a deployed app.  For example, functions that reference them.  It seems to behave differently than local R env.

Comment: I figured this out.  Just was a package issue where instance didn't have packages installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.  Maps was not installed